# Finding the sum of Binomial Coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

The question says to find the value of $$\binom{n}{1} \cdot \left( \sum ^1 _ {r=0} \binom{1}{r}\right) + \binom{n}{2} \cdot \left( \sum ^2 _ {r=0} \binom{2}{r}\right) + \binom{n}{3} \cdot \left( \sum ^3 _ {r=0} \binom{3}{r}\right) \ldots \binom{n}{n} \cdot \left( \sum ^n _ {r=0} \binom{n}{r}\right)$$ 
I wrote $$\left( \sum ^n _ {r=0} \binom{n}{r}\right) = 2^n$$ Which gives us a series like this, 
$$\binom{n}{1} \cdot 2 + \binom{n}{2} \cdot 2^2 +  \ldots \binom{n}{n} \cdot 2^n$$ 
But I am not able to figure out what to do from here.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How would you expand $(1+2)^n?$ using the Binomial Theorem?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe Using the Binomial expansion I expect I would get something, like, $\binom{n}{0} \cdot 1 + \binom{n}{1} \cdot 2 + \ldots + \binom{n}{n-1} \cdot 2^{n-1} + \binom{n}{n} \cdot 2^n$

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Comment: *Mathematica* yields $3^n-1$.

Comment: Obviously since the first term is missing. Thank you